# Can videoing burning magnesium damage a camera sensor?

Tags: equipment-damage, light, video

I have possibly had the misfortune of videoing a bright performance of burning magnesium at night before I realized what it was. I probably filmed it for 10-15 seconds and now I am wondering if it could have caused damage to my camera's sensor (and how I can tell if it did).

I have a Nikon D7100.

Comment: Is there any damage to the camera? Is there any problem with photos you've taken since then?

Comment: I haven't noticed any damage. I am going to try Rafael's method below and will get back to everyone.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a methodology to find it:

1. Prepare a white screen on you computer, for example a white document in GIMP.
2. Take an out-of-focus photo, for example, focus at infinity and the widest aperture to avoid vignetting.
3. Use different settings. Overexpose until the histogram is almost to the right. Underexpose until the histogram is almost to the left.
4. Open the images in Photoshop (or whatever) and using Levels, drag the opposite level a lot to contrast the almost white and almost black images.

If you see the pattern of what you video looked, yes probably you did.
If not, good for you.

**Please post your results here so we know!**